# How to force child div to overflow it's parent width but only to the width of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

So let me start with the JSFiddle example - [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/A5wge/1/).

The problem is with the styling/positioning of the div with class `class="overflow-parent"`. The name of the class is descriptive for the current problem, but in fact it's the div that's supposed to display the site content.

The horizontal divs and the vertical div with the red border are for the navigation features that I'll provide and I want my content to be displayed inside them which in terms of this example means :

- The content (the green-bordered div with `aaaaa..` paragraph should be positioned next to the red vertical menu and not overflowing it too like it's happening right now.
- The `class="overflow-parent"` should overflow it's parent on the right side but only to reach the size of the screen. Not as you can see now - with the horizontal scroll.

Also as sub problems - I would like my vertical menu (the red-bordered div) to be at least with the height of the display and if the content is bigger then the height of the screen then to adjust it's height to be equal with that of the `<div class="overflow-parent">` which is supposed to show the page content.

Also - I don't have much experience with designing but the structure and the approach are entirely mine and it's possible to have a much better and/or easier approach to achieve the final result and I don't mind such an answer. Just to keep the same final appearance as it is now (without the problem ofcourse).

**EDIT**
It's important to keep the navigation centered, that's why the `.container` class is

```
.container {
  width: 970px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

I need it `970px;` and centered, so it's expected to have white space on both ends. The tricky part is that because of the vertical menu the left side will remain empty white, but I want to use the right side at it fullest but not exceeding the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

*The content (the green-bordered div with aaaaa.. paragraph should be positioned next to the red vertical menu and not overflowing it too like it's happening right now.*

Remove the `position: absolute;`

*The class="overflow-parent" should overflow it's parent on the right side but only to reach the size of the screen. Not as you can see now - with the horizontal scroll.*

Setting the width to auto (`width: auto;`) should solve this.

I add some properties:

to `.vertical-menu`

```
width: 25%;
```

to `.overflow-parent`

```
  width: auto;
  max-width: 72.6%; /* -(.4%) to compesate the border width */
  word-wrap:break-word; /* To prevent big words to break the layout */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A5wge/4/

Comment: With what you suggest the div is positioned below the vertical (red border) menu, and I still get it wider than the screen.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I haven't explained well. The idea is to align the `<div class="overflow-parent">` with the width of the screen or in other words the `<div id="top-nav-wrapper">`. In your example, everything is centered which is not the desired effect, I want my content to take all the space left to the right.

Comment: Sorry, I see that I haven't explained everything as good as I should, read the edit pls.